# Filtering a comboxes remote store locally in ExtJs

Tags: json, combobox, extjs

I have an ExtJs combobox. Its store loaded using JSON (using MyStore class below). I want to load all the values to the store, and then filter them with the text entered in the combo's textfield (preferably using the typeAhead feature).

The problem is that I want to do the filtering on the client side (combo's mode property is 'remote', by default). I don't want my combo to reload its store every time I type something.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Here's my store class :

```
MyStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.JsonStore, {
    constructor: function(jsonUrl, storeId, id, description, isAutoLoad, cfg) {
        cfg = cfg || {};
        GenericStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
            storeId: storeId,
            root: 'result',
            url: jsonUrl,
            autoLoad: isAutoLoad,
            fields: [
                {
                    name: id
                },
                {
                    name: description
                }
            ]
        }, cfg));
    }    
});
```

And the combo :

```
            xtype: 'combo',
            fieldLabel: 'The Combo',
            width: 150,
            store: myStoreData,
            valueField: 'id',
            displayField: 'name',
            minChars : 0,
            editable : false,
            itemId : 'my-combo'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this you must:

1. Construct MyStore class with "isAutoLoad" config option as "true"
2. In your combobox config set the "mode" config option to "local" (see Built the combo config code bellow for another config)

Here is my short example:

Construct myStoreData variable

```
var myStoreData = new MyStore({
    autoLoad: true, //so the store will load automatically
    ...any_other_config_option...
});
```

Built the combo config

```
{
     xtype: 'combo',
     fieldLabel: 'The Combo',
     width: 150,
     store: myStoreData, 
    // myStoreData is already loaded before as it have 'autoLoad' config set to true 
    // and act as localstore to populate the combo box item 
    // when the combo "mode" config set to 'local'
     valueField: 'id',
     displayField: 'name',
     minChars : 0,
     editable : true, //before was editable : false,
     itemId : 'my-combo',
     mode: 'local', // by default this was mode: 'remote'
     typeAhead: true // by default this was typeAhead: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. (Though it's not isAutoLoad, but autoLoad, tried to edit it, but I don't have edit privilege) I could not use the autoLoad feature because of restrictions specific to my project, but I loaded the store manually on combo's focus event and it worked fine on 'local' mode combos.

Comment: Glad to know its help you. Good luck with your project

Comment: This does not work for me. I use ExtJS 4.2 and I set `queryMode: 'local'`, but it essentially just calls `store.filter()`, which loads the store, when the store has configuration `remoteFilter: true`.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the store.filter() method.  You can use this to use user-entered information to filter your store that the combo box uses.  This is taken from the ExtJS API documentation for data.store.

```
store.filter([
{
property     : 'name',
value        : 'Ed',
anyMatch     : true, //optional, defaults to true
caseSensitive: true  //optional, defaults to true
},
//filter functions can also be passed
{
fn   : function(record) {
return record.get('age') == 24
},
scope: this
}
]);
```

Comment: Yes, the combo calls this method in its doQuery method. Do you mean I should override this method? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: Is the initial data set static?  you *could* output this to a json file that can be used to populate your local data store.  You can then try to use the mode:local option.... From there you can use a reference to the store used by the combo box to execute the filter() method.  See Gajahlemu's code... There's a lot of good settings in there for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to add the config option `lastQuery:''` to the combo.

explanation : http://progex.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/extjs-combo-dropdown-does-not-filter-on-first-trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Add listener to your store on 'load' event, do filtering, by removing or flagging records, if removing it is clear load to combo component, if flagging you need to recognize those flaggs in combo and display or not...

It hard to go with more details if I do not see your code for store and combo, so I can give you only general idea